# How to get percentage values in ggplot with 2 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom, geom-col

I am currently working on a project regarding buying behaviour.

First I need to filter the data set because I only want to look at data which has a specific variable at one. Then I want to plot the data from this specific variable, distinguishing between A and B on x axis and having The Units on the y axis, unfortunately units are not the same for each data point so I cannot use a bar plot. My code currently is:

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(SES == "1") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = brand, y = unit)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(y = "Units sold",
       x = "Brand", title="Buying Behaviour SES 1") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 15)
```

This code works, but it does not show the results in percentage but rather in absolut value. I need to compare different SES and the absolute values differ strongly so I want to go with percentages instead. How would you guys change to percentage?

```
aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))
```

using this does work for a bar plot if i leave out units, but I need to leave units in.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What kind of 'units' do you mean, and where do you want to leave them in?

Comment: @CasparV. Sorry for the bad explanation. This data set shows purchases in a store. The whole data set only has purchases of one product category, cheese. Each purchase is listed as an entry but not each purchase has the same amount of units purchased. I dont want to compare the amount of purchases but rather the amount of units purchased. Hope this explains the issue better.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?